# Cassandra SELECT BETWEEN two dates

Tags: sql, cql, between, cql3

How can i convert below SQL query to CQL query?

```
SELECT * FROM csv_report WHERE sensor_id=170268 AND create_day BETWEEN 20150401 AND 20150403;
```

also i trying different BETWEEN query:

```
SELECT * FROM csv_report WHERE sensor_id=170268 AND create_day >= 20150401 AND create_day <= 20150403;
```

But this query raised an error:

> code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Only EQ and IN relation are supported on the partition key (unless you use the token() function)"

Comment: Well for SQL Server at least, normally dates go in single quotes. So something like create_day BETWEEN '20150401' AND '20150403'. I don't think you can put in 00 for the day.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan, but i work on available cassandra db, and i must get data from this type of db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM csv_report 
WHERE sensor_id=170268 
AND create_day IN (20150401, 20150402, 20150403);
```

Comment: The reason this is likely to work is that, based on the error, you (Mohsen)  have both sensor_id and create_day as elements in the partition key portion of the primary key.

When doing a SELECT, cassandra will hash the values of the partition key to determine which nodes hold the partitions, so using a range in the WHERE clause is unsupported. If you need to use ranges/inequality, you must use them on the clustering key portion of the primary key.